# reading from configuration database inside of data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to create a data factory pipeline to move data from sftp to blob storage. At this point, I'm only doing a POC, and I'd like know how I would read configuration settings and kick off my pipeline based on those configuration settings.

Example of config settings would be **(note that there would be around 1000 of these):**

```
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
|    sftp server     | sftp user | sftp pass |       blob dest        |    interval    |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
| sftp.microsoft.com | alex      | myPass    | /myContainer/destroot1 | every 12 hours |
+--------------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------+----------------+
```

**How do you kick off a pipeline using some external configuration file/store?**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Lookup activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity) and [linked service Parameterize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services)